# Storing ajax output into variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

I have to check weather invoice number is duplicate or not for that i am using following ajax.

```
function check_duplicate_invoice(num){
          var isDuplicate ;

          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
           xmlhttp.open("GET","check_duplicate_invoice.php?in="+num, true);
           xmlhttp.send();
           xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                    isDuplicate =xmlhttp.responseText.trim() // reponceText will be 0 or 1
                }
            }

            alert(isDuplicate); //result undefined

            if(isDuplicate== 1){
                alert("Invoice Number Already Exist");
            }
    }
```

I am not able to store ajax output into isDuplicate variable. Please help.

Comment: Did you try to alert `xmlhttp.responseText.trim()` in the first place to see if it has a value at all?

Comment: you should use `alert(isDuplicate)` inside the success function.  in your case.  the `xmlhttp.readyState == 4...`

Comment: @roullie Could be me, but since he's declaring the variable outside the function, but within the same function as the alert, that shouldn't matter.

Comment: If you are using `jQuery` you can make you life easier, if you use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) methods

Comment: @icecub It does matter, since he is calling that `alert` before that AJAX request returns the data. That's why `isDuplicate` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

That's because ajax calls are asynchronous. You are looking at the variable before the request has had a time to complete. Try this:

```
function check_duplicate_invoice(num){
      var isDuplicate ;

      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xmlhttp.open("GET","check_duplicate_invoice.php?in="+num, true);
       xmlhttp.send();
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                isDuplicate =xmlhttp.responseText.trim() // reponceText will be 0 or 1
                alert(isDuplicate); //result undefined

                if(isDuplicate== 1){
                   alert("Invoice Number Already Exist");
                }

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Tried your answer its working in firefox but not in chrome browser. I have to use this in crome. Please help in this matter

Comment: what happens in Chrome?

Comment: Nothing happens in Chrome

Comment: Something would definitely be happening in chrome. Open the developer console and check for errors. Post the code that calls this method (update your question with that code)

Comment: I dont know how to use developer console for finding errors. Can you please help

Comment: We are getting way beyond the original question now. and this is the first result for a search for " how to use developer console"